# Guardar valor geojson

Tags: php, json

Como é que ao fazer um `geojson` eu conseguiria gravar números em vez de string.

Exemplo:

```
$geojson = array(
    'type'      => 'FeatureCollection',
    'features'  => array()
);

while( ($registo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) !=null)
{
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature', 
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array($registo['x'], $registo['y'])
        ),
        'properties' => array(
            'id_publicidade' => $registo['id_publicidade'],
            'id_utilizador' => $registo['id_utilizador'],
            'nome' => $registo['nome'],
            'categoria' => $registo['categoria'],
        )
    );
array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
};
echo json_encode($geojson);
```

A minha questão está na parte: `'coordinates' => array($registo['x'], $registo['y'])`

Ao fazer o `echo` do `json` o resultado é: 
`"coordinates":["-8.847618468261716","41.693271914384525"]`

Eu quero que não me apreçam as aspas, quero que o json fique sem àspas, porque ao continuar o meu código as áspas conseguem de alguma forma interferir com as coordenadas.

Comment: Já testaste usando o `floatval()`? Assim: `'coordinates' => array(floatval($registo['x']), floatval($registo['y']))`

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar o [floatval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) que converte uma *string* em valor com parte fracional:

```
'coordinates' => array(floatval($registo['x']), floatval($registo['y']))
                          ^                        ^
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo, desconhecia totalmente isso.
Muito obrigado!